Uniqueness for a certain quasilinear boundary-value problem
For $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ being smooth, and satisfying $xh'(x)>h(x)$, I'm trying to show uniqueness for the following BVP
$$\begin{cases}u\Delta u=h(u),&\text{in}\ U\\
u=1,& \text{in}\ \partial U\end{cases}$$
Under the condition that $u>0$.
So far I've tried applying integration by parts in various ways, and considering $w:=u-v$ with $u$ and $v$ both solving the BVP, but nothing seems to quite work.
Can anyone help?

Let \begin{align*}
g(t)= \frac{h(t)}t \qquad \text{for } t>0.
\end{align*} Then $u$ and $v$ satisfy \begin{align*}
\Delta u =g(u) \qquad \text{in } U,
\end{align*} so if $w=u-v$ we have \begin{align*}
\Delta w&=g(u)-g(v) \\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt} g(tu+(1-t)v)\, dt \\
&= \bigg [ \int_0^1 g’(tu(x)+(1-t)v(x))\, dt \bigg] w(x).
\end{align*} If we call $$c(x)=\int_0^1 g’(tu(x)+(1-t)v(x))\,dt, $$ it follows that $$\tag{$\ast$}\left\{\begin{array}{rll}
{}-\Delta w +cw&=0&\text{in } U\\ w&=0 &\text{on } \partial U.
\end{array} \right.$$ Furthermore, $$g’(t) = \frac{th’(t)-h(t)}{t^2}\geq 0  $$ by assumption, so $c\geq0$. Thus, the classical maximum principle applied to $(\ast)$ gives $w=0$.
